# Derivative notation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I can understand how the answer was derived, but why was dy/dx rewritten into d/dx? where has the y gone to?

[image]

Comment: It has not gone anywhere $y=2x^{-1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of different notations. For instance, if $y=f(x)$ is derivable then the derivate can be written as $f'(x)$, $y'$, $\frac{dy}{dx}$, $\frac{df}{dx}$, $\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]$ or even $D_x(f(x))$.

In particular the notations  $\frac{df}{dx}$, $\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ are called the Leibniz's notations.

Comment: if f prime of x -> this statement refers to derivative as well? I often heard this during the lecture.

Comment: Yes, it does. That is written as $f'(x)$, which is the derivative of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Is it clearer to see what happened when it written like this?
$$\begin{align} y & = 2 x^{-1}
\\[2ex]\therefore\quad \tfrac{\mathrm d\,y}{\mathrm d\,x}&= \tfrac{\mathrm d\,[2 x^{-1}]}{\mathrm d\,x~~\quad} \\[1ex] &=\tfrac{\mathrm d ~~~}{\mathrm d\,x}[2x^{-1}] \\[1ex] & = 2\tfrac{\mathrm d ~~~}{\mathrm d\,x}[x^{-1}]  
\end{align}$$

Depending on typesetting, it is often clearer to write the differential term to the right of the Lebnitz' operator than *scrunch* it into the "numerator".   It means the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

By the same reason why $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{b}a$. The reason why this answer representation has been used is context dependent and does not related to this derivative directly that could be written as $\frac{dy}{dx}=-2x^{-2}$.